# How to visualize the proximity between two stochastic processes?

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, convergence, approximation

I am studying a certain convergence of time series. And I would like to "make sure" that the convergence to a certain process actually happens. So, consider the following simplification.

Consider Gaussian autoregressive processes. We know that, in some sense, the processes
$$X_t = 0.7 X_{t-1}+ u_t \quad \hbox{ and }\quad X_t = (0.7 + 1/n) X_{t-1}+ u_t $$
are close to each other.

Something I've always asked myself, how to visualize (or suspect) a certain proximity between the two processes?

For example, consider these two realizations (n=10):
[image]
Something that is obvious is that even if the realizations are close, this is not the correct way to visualize the proximity between the processes. For example, adding the process $X_t = 0.1 X_{t-1}+ u_t$ (a process that is "far away" from the first two processes), we get this:
[image]
I believe there should be some formal tests to test this. It would be nice to incorporate into the R language (or other) some way to test or measure this proximity. But I would also be satisfied with an alternative approach (graphical or otherwise).